# "Are those a new [object]?"

Tags: grammaticality

Is this question grammatical:

> Are those a new [object]?

I know that the singular form of that question, "*Is that a new [object]?*", sound perfectly fine but the collective form of it sounds odd, at least for me?

Comment: No, it is not grammatical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skip the indefinite article 'a', and you're set.

> Are those new shoes?

For collectives, use the singular as you normally would in a non-question.

> Is that a new solar system?
>
> Is that a new set of planets?
>
> Are those new planets?

Answer (score 2):

First, a basic grammatical point. Copular verbs like *be* don't have objects. The words that follow them form the **complement** or, more precisely, the **subject predicative.**

The normal patterns are, to continue the interrogative construcion:

> Is that a new hat?

and

> Are those new shoes?

However, it is just about possible to imagine a native speaker saying:

> Are those a new pair of glasses?

Here the plural form of *glasses* overrides the singular form of *a new pair*.

Comment: Yes, the only case I could think of also was the English "dual-with-classifier" e.g. "Are those a new pair of pants"?